# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Service - Angular 4.1.2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

Im pretty new in Angular, and i'm having annoying problem which i dont understand. I want to inject my service to @NgModule so that i can use it anywhere in application without needing to declare or import it again. Then when i run my project everything is fine after refresh page and get this exception:

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Service

**make.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MakeService {
    originUrl;
    constructor(private http: Http, @Inject('ORIGIN_URL') originUrl: string) {
        this.originUrl = originUrl;
    }

    getMakes() {
        return this.http.get(this.originUrl + '/api/makes')
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    getFeatures() {
        return this.http.get(this.originUrl + '/api/features')
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

}
```

This service im declaring in **app.module.ts**:

```
import { MakeService } from './services/make.service';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { sharedConfig } from './app.module.shared';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        ...sharedConfig.imports
    ],
    declarations: sharedConfig.declarations,
    bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
    providers: [MakeService, { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin }]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

And finally use it in my component **vehicle-form.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MakeService } from '../../services/make.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vehicle-form',
  templateUrl: './vehicle-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vehicle-form.component.css'],
})
export class VehicleFormComponent implements OnInit {
    makes;
    vehicle = {};
    constructor(private makeService: MakeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.makeService.getMakes().subscribe(makes => {
          this.makes = makes
          console.log("MAKES", this.makes);
      });
  }

  onMakeChange() {
      console.log("VEHICLE", this.vehicle);
  }

}
```

When im declaring provider in my component like this:

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-vehicle-form',
  templateUrl: './vehicle-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vehicle-form.component.css'],
  providers: [MakeService]
})
...
```

Then everything is working but thats not what i want to archive.

Comment: what module is `app-vehicle-form` in? is it by any chance lazy loaded?

Comment: @Maximus its in the app.module.shared.ts file do you want me to show code from it? i dont know if its lazy loaded how can i check it ?

Comment: do you use routing?

Answer (score 0):

@Maximus yes i'm using routing. I dont know why angular CLI generated 3 separated files instead one.

Soo those three files are: 
app.module.server.ts, app.module.shared.ts, app.module.client.ts

I had to rename app.module.client to app.module.ts to generate component from CLI becouse there was error that app.module file is missing.

Soo i think the app.module.client is now old app.module file which imports the 2 other files app.module.server and app.module.shared.

The **app.module.shared** file look like:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { VehicleFormComponent } from './components/vehicle-form/vehicle-form.component';

export const sharedConfig: NgModule = {
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        VehicleFormComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'vehicles/new', component: VehicleFormComponent },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are tilting at windmills. I would better export your constant as static field in some class:

**some.settings.ts**

```
export class SomeSettings {
   public static ORIGIN_URL=window.location.origin;
}
```

And then use it in **make.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MakeService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { 
        const settings = require( './some.settings' );
        this.SomeSettings = settings.SomeSettings;
    }
    SomeSettings: any;

    getMakes() {
        return this.http.get(SomeSettings.ORIGIN_URL + '/api/makes')
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    getFeatures() {
        return this.http.get(SomeSettings.ORIGIN_URL + '/api/features')
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Comment: ReferenceError: location is not defined

Comment: @Voque, Try to exclude library from prerendering

Answer (score 0):

I am also seeing the same problem with you. But when I put the provider declaration (dependency injection) inside app.component.ts, which is my root component, the issue is not seen with me anymore.

Best,